# How to change the value of a sanity field

Tags: react-native, sanity

So i want to change the value of a specific field called "likes"

Here is the schema:

```
//...
fields: [
          {
            name: "likes",
            title: "Likes",
            type: "number",
          }
]
```

I want to change the like count when a button is pressed. it should change the like count by +1.

How to change the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`client.patch(doc).inc({likes: 1}).commit()`](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#incrementing-decrementing-numbers) to increment your `likes` field each time it's called.